# jQuery Mobile - Dialog not applying jQuery styling second time around?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery mobile dialog which works perfectly the first time it's loaded, but once the `dialog.close();` button or back button in the browser is clicked and the dialog is initiated again, the dialog is not wrapped in jQuery UI tags and no styling is applied to it.

It works the first time but never again after that. I am assuming it may because the old data may be present in the DOM, but when inspecting the page with firebug I can't find the old data present. I have noticed that after the first initiation, it uses the same jQuery ID on every instance of `element.data();`

Here is an example of the console.logs:

```
Before the dialog is ever created:
Object { jQuery16102984105026891979={...}, role="dialog"}

After it has been created:
Object { jQuery16102984105026891979={...}, role="dialog", page={...}, more...}

After the `dialog.close();` function has been activated:
Object { jQuery16102984105026891979={...}, role="dialog", page={...}, more...}

After it has been created again:
Object { jQuery16102984105026891979={...}, role="dialog", page={...}, more...}
```

How come the styling isn't being applied the second time? The dialog is being initiated with `$.mobile.changePage()`.

I don't really have any code to show as the application is built in MVC and it would be a huge effort to try and reproduce the problem.

I found a similar unanswered issue on jquery.com: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dialog-not-applying-style-on-second-time-loading .

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I have the same problem and it's driving me crazy!